# Python matplotlib doesnt animate. Chart just shows up

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code with work for me. However, The issue is that the chart will just display everything inside of the excel file without animating anything. How can I convert this to make it so my plots animate when the program runs?

```
def formatY(x, pos):
    s = '%d' % x
    groups = []
    while s and s[-1].isdigit():
        groups.append(s[-3:])
        s = s[:-3]
    return s + ','.join(reversed(groups))

def animate(i):
    df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='name')
    x = df['Date']
    y = df['Total']

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x, y, label='Total')

    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=.20)
    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=.20)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.autoscale()
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)

    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_format)



ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval = 1000)
y_format = tkr.FuncFormatter(formatY)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The basic form of an Excel file is not to call it in an animation function, but to take the data once loaded and update it into a graph template.[https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/animation_api.html](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/animation_api.html)

Comment: you should update you data `x` and `y` through `animate(i)`

Comment: @ted930511 but hoe